# Getting an error from Server as "message": "Unexpected token d"

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongoose

I am getting an error from server as 500 when request is sent from browser and 400 when request is sent from Postman. Below is my JSON

```
{ dishes:
   [ { _id: '584ae32eb4e5ec277c8dbcab',
       name: 'Uthapizza',
       price: 499,
       image: 'images/uthapizza.png' },
     { _id: '584ae346b4e5ec277c8dbcb1',
       name: 'Zucchipakoda',
       price: 199,
       image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png' },
     { _id: '584ae359b4e5ec277c8dbcb7',
       name: 'Vadonut',
       price: 199,
       image: 'images/vadonut.png' } ],
  sum: 8.97,
  postedBy: '584ae0ca2e678112b03f8a47',
  _id: 58519897c777f922646a5215 }
```

The associated mongoose schema is

```
var orderSchema = new Schema({
    dishes: [ {
        _id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        price: {
            type: Currency,
            required: true
        },
        image: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
    ],
    sum: 
    {
        type: Currency,
        required: true
    },
    postedBy: 
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
},
{
        timestamps: true
});
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Thanks for your time

regards,
Raj

Comment: Can you show how you access the database as well?

Comment: @Raj R - Add more code as to what exactly you are trying to do using this schema ? Problem may not be with your schema but with the actual code.

Comment: Please show some more code, where you think the problem lies. please show how you are fetching data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a valid `json`:

- `json` strings surrounded by double quotes.
- keys aren't valid either (not a valid value: a string without double quotes)

Remember, it is `json`, not `JavaScript`.

Here is a valid json document:

```
{ "dishes":
   [ { "_id": "584ae32eb4e5ec277c8dbcab",
       "name": "Uthapizza",
       "price": 499,
       "image": "images/uthapizza.png" },
     { "_id": "584ae346b4e5ec277c8dbcb1",
       "name": "Zucchipakoda",
       "price": 199,
       "image": "images/zucchipakoda.png" },
     { "_id": "584ae359b4e5ec277c8dbcb7",
       "name": "Vadonut",
       "price": 199,
       "image": "images/vadonut.png" } ],
  "sum": 8.97,
  "postedBy": "584ae0ca2e678112b03f8a47",
  "_id": "58519897c777f922646a5215" }
```